# Attach document using carrierwave from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, attachment

I have a document 'example.docx' located in public folder of my app.

I want **to create a subject record from the console that has that document attached** using carrierwave gem like this:

```
Subject.create(group_id: 3, type: 1, attachment: __________)
```

subject.rb:

```
mount_uploader :attachment, FileUploader
```

I tried to do as it is written in documentation:

```
subject = Subject.new
File.open("public/example.docx") do |f|
  subject.attachment = f
end
subject.save!
```

But `subject.attachment.url` results in `` NoMethodError: undefined method `url' for "#<File.........>":String ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `FileUploader` in the file `app/uploaders/file_uploader.rb` then it sounds like it's probably an app restarting and/or spring issue - ie. that your app hasn't fully/successfully reloaded the uploader.

So:

1. Stop your console and server.
2. Stop spring `spring stop` (or kill the processes).
3. Start your console.
4. Try creating/saving again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, smathy!